# How to access iframe javascript variable from parent page when accessing cross domain in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to access a java script variable in the iframe page. I want to access from both same domain and cross domain.

**Javascript & HTML**

```
function CallIframeVariable() {
    var iframeVar = window.myIframe.myVar;
}
<iframe src="iframepage.html" onload="CallIframeVariable();">
```

iframepage.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<script>
    myVar = "Manivasagan";
</script>
```

How can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent.iframeVar` in you iframe, but that will only work if **both iframe and main window is on same domain**. Otherwise, it would not work due to cross-domain security policy.

Comment: How can i overcome cross-domain security policy. Please advice me. It will help lot.

Comment: @Manivasagan There is no straightforward way to do it, it is browser setting. Although try adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header to the server response. But, it will not work in all browsers i think.